# How can I share my Android application to facebook

Tags: android, facebook

How can I share my Android application to facebook with its Image. I have taken my App Id and shared some posts as wallposts. Some dynamic values should be posted on the post. Main motive is to share app like the image is attached here.[image: The Image attached here is just an example of app developed in Iphone.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Android market
2. Search for your app
3. Copy the link
4. Share the link in Facebook, choose pic from the thumbnail options.

Comment: Thanks Rahul... In case, how can I remove the copied link that is also showing on the top of the post..

Comment: Once you got the information fetched on facebook, you can delete the original link and type whatever you like. Also don't forget to accept the solution and upvote if it worked for you.

Comment: Actually I am developing an Android Application and in that application, the whole process, I mentioned here should be on a Button Click. I can not use browser nor facebook native application... In that case If i send a link (that u suggested) from the application in programatic manner, the application should be  shared at facebook...

Comment: I believe Ayush must be using be using facebook social oauth based api for sharing. If that is the case, they will have specific api for link sharing. You would need to explore it, if you don't understand it you can post it as a question here and some gentlemen will answer that